# CSS - Show/Hide elements based on CheckBox

Tags: html, css

I have a project where I show and hide elements using checkboxes in conjunction mit CSS only. The following pattern, see also https://jsfiddle.net/37bqmbuo/, works for me.

HTML:

```
<input class="switch-1" type="checkbox">
<input class="switch-2" type="checkbox">
<input class="switch-3" type="checkbox">
<div class="hidden-1 hidden-2">Info 1</div>
<div class="hidden-2 hidden-3">Info 2</div>
<div class="hidden-1 hidden-3">Info 3</div>
<div class="hidden-1">Info 4</div>
<div class="hidden-3">Info 5</div>
```

CSS:

```
.switch-1:checked ~ .hidden-1
{
   display: none;
}

.switch-2:checked ~ .hidden-2
{
   display: none;
}

.switch-3:checked ~ .hidden-3
{
   display: none;
}
```

But the more options I have, the more classes I need to create. Is there a smarter way to implement this with CSS only?

Comment: an example here http://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/tpmAi

Comment: I don't think you can do it without js

Comment: why are you not use js?

Comment: I guess you use concepts like LESS to create it for you? But not sure if the original problem of repeating can be avoided in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is.

Put the element you want to target after the input like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="My Checkbox" />
<div class="toggle">Toggle me</div>
```

and do some CSS magic:

```
input:checked + .toggle { display: none; }
```

Comment: how this answer can solve the OP issue? He already knows this _css magic_, please read carefully the question.

Comment: He asked If there is a way generating less classes. So in my example you would need only one.

Comment: But OP has multiple inputs, did you read carefully the question?

Comment: He targets all inputs with this input:checked + .toggle { display: none; } line of css, so the answer is quite valid imho. However, I would probably use one separate class on all inputs to target them specifically.